# Horizontal line behind a heading in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve a horizontal line behind a heading as shown below.

[image]

I can do that fairly easily with a div around the heading.  Something like:

```css
  .holder{
    height:4px;
    background:red;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
  }
  h4{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    background:white;
    line-height:50px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin-top:-23px;
    font-size:30px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <h4>
    TESTING
  </h4>
</div>
```

But I would like to be able to do the same without adding the exterior `div`.  The closest I have got is:

```css
  h3{
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    position:relative;
    font-size:30px;
  }
  
  h3::before{
    display:block;
    background:red;
    width:100%;
    height:4px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-3px;
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
  }
```

```html
<h3>
  TESTING
</h3>
```

Which results in the following:

[image]

Can anyone suggest how I might do this without adding the `div`?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve what you want as below, using `::before`, `::after`, and CSS Grid Layout:

```css
h3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  font-size: 30px;
}

h3::before,
h3::after {
  background: red;
  height: 4px;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<h3>
  TESTING
</h3>
```